# Is it Possible to run a C# website in Apache?

Tags: windows, ssl, apache2.4, c#

I have a client that has had a very large website with ssl that was written in C# and I was wanting to know is it possible to run this all windows website in a Linux atmosphere?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612092/porting-asp-net-application-to-mono-apache-under-linux.

Comment: [ASP.NET hosting with Apache](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/#aspnet-hosting-with-apache) (with [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/)) might be relevant.